# Polygon shapefile shows weird

Tags: qgis

I am a total newbee to GIS and currently using QGIS. I have opened a shapefile which should give information about the European subsurface, but everything becomes colored but I do still see the outlines of the polygons.

I've now had this with two different datasets so I figured nothing is wrong with the files but with the program instead. Can someone tell me how this can be solved?

Edit: this image is extremely small, but this is what it should approximately look like:
[image: What it now looks like]
[image: What I want it to look like]

Comment: Looks like a classified satellite image. i-click the parts you dont want to show, pick some attribute and use it to filter. For example something like `"category" != 'Ocean'`. Then style/symbolize it

Comment: You need to do some classification in the symbology tab of the layers properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A priori the shapefile doesn't contain a style file.
You can create a style by classifying the data. Double-click on the file in the "layer" tab. In the window that opens, under "Symbology", choose "Categorized". Below, in "value", choose the field which contains the information you want to display (geology?). Now you have only to click on "Classify" and than "OK".